# How to request multiple inputs, n number of times

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

For the code below, I want to take the input values `b` and `k`, `n` times:

```
syms Q i w h2 h1 k

% n is number of layers for computation

n = input (' ')

for j = 1:n

k1 = input (' '); b1 = input (' ');

% up to... 

k(n) = input (' '); b(n) = input (' ');

% so that i want to use the various inputs of b and k to calculate Q.

Qi=( -b(i) * k(i) )*((h2-h1)/w)

Q=symsum(Qi, i, 1, 3)
```

Comment: Your code block has serious indexing problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your loop, you can prompt for the input and store it into an array of `k` and `b` values

```
% Pre-allocate k and b arrays
k = zeros(1, n);
b = zeros(1, n);

for ind = 1:n
    % Prompt for the next k value
    k(ind) = input('');

    % Prompt for the next b value
    b(ind) = input('');
end
```

Alternately, you could prompt the user for an array directly

```
k = input('Please enter an array for k in the form [k1, k2, k3]');
b = input('Please enter an array for b in the form [b1, b2, b3]');
```

Using these arrays you could compute `Q` for each value of `k` and `b`

```
Q = (-b .* k)*((h2-h1)/w);
```

Comment: Suever... Thank you very much. You always come to my aid. I will try iy right away.

Comment: @user6086432 If it works for you consider marking it as a solution